# Angular custom directive link function won't accept 'restrict'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am just playing with a custom directive, an example of which I have [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/88Xwn1ZyfiTp14UYpYw6?p=preview).

As is it displays as expected, but as soon as I add a `restrict: 'E'` to the scope, as in plunker file **car.js** as in the following (uncomment the line)

```
function CarCard() {

return {
  scope: {
   // restrict: 'E', // uncomment this and it breaks
    car: '='
  },
```

I get

> Invalid isolate scope definition for directive 'myCarCard'.
>   Definition: {... restrict: 'E' ...}

I have been looking at the doco for hours, I just cannot see what is wrong here (I am sure I have spelt `restrict` and `'E'` correctly.

Although it works without it, I would very much like to know why my restrict does not work.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`restrict` should be outside of `scope`.

If you put it inside scope,it'll consider it as a property of scope and check for bindings.

Bindings with scope are `@` , `=` , `&` .

So your `restrict: 'E',` inside `scope` is not valid.

try like this

```
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {
    car: '='
  },
```

<kbd>**[`PLNKR`](http://plnkr.co/edit/69hX9saUG9wnRZ31ZrVE?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Oh, exactly like the doco says (I must be blind!) Thankyou very much for that Anik!